# Stuff function in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select STUFF(
STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([run_duration] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
            , 3, 0, ':')
        , 6, 0, ':') 
    AS [LastRunDuration (HH:MM:SS)]
 from sysjobhistory
```

The query I have given above works fine but I am trying to understand it more clear. My observations are:

1. First we cast the run duration into `varchar` and with a length 6 and append six 0's to right of it which becomes if its is `10` then `00000010`
2. After we use the stuff function to insert `:`  in between this here it is at the 3rd position so the above one becomes `00:000010`
3. Again we use stuff  to insert the `:` symbol to the sixth position so it becomes `00:00:0010`

But when I run the query if there is a values `10` it shows as `00:00:10`.

How that can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first bullet you say the value becomes 00000010. That is incorrect. It actually becomes 000010 because of the RIGHT( , 6).

To clarify, compare the difference:

```
SELECT LEFT('00000010', 6), RIGHT('00000010', 6);
```

Results:

```
------  ------
000000  000010
```

Comment: but when using RIGHT() in the above exp it's right(00000010,6) which gives you the output 000000,so how it will become 000010

Comment: I think you are mixing up LEFT and RIGHT. Did you try both using a simple example?

Comment: oops yes aaron i just thought the reverse thanks for helping me